# AWS CDK (Python) adding dynamodb:Query permission for one or more global secondary indexes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have a CDK deployed Python Lambda function currently failing to execute queries against a DynamoDb table because the permission isn't there for utilising the referenced index:

*(AccessDeniedException) when calling the Query operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:xxx/index/my-index because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action*

At present I'm using the following CDK commands to assign DynamoDb permissions to the Lambda function(s). What would I need to specify in order to add query permissions for index(es)?

```
# grant permissions for lambda to read/write to DynamoDB table and bucket
table.grant_read_write_data(lambda_function)
table.grant_read_data(api_lambda_function)

bucket.grant_read_write(lambda_function)
bucket_storage.grant_read_write(lambda_function)
bucket_storage.grant_read(api_lambda_function)
```

Comment: How do you create the secondary index?

Comment: At the moment, manually. I did have a bunch of table.add_global_secondary_index commands in the CDK, but had to comment them out as you can't apply more than one GSI in a single table operation (so the CDK fails if you have more than one referenced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've created the indexes outside the CDK, you will have to add the permissions yourself.  Pass a [PolicyStatement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/PolicyStatement.html#aws_cdk.aws_iam.PolicyStatement) to [function.add_to_role_policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function.add_to_role_policy). A broad set of statement `actions` can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/iam-policy-specific-table-indexes.html).  Narrow them as appropriate.  Specify the index resource as: `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:0123456789012:table/MyTable/index/MyIndex` (`index/*` for all indexes).

N.B. CDK will add the permissions if you create the index with `add_global_secondary_index`.  You can call this method multiple times when *creating* the table.  During subsequent table *updates*, however, DynamoDB limits you to [one new GSI per update operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating).

Comment: Thanks fedonev, but if I try to call the method multiple times within the same CDK script, I get the error:  ❌  APIDocumentStorageStack failed: Error: The stack named APIDocumentStorageStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Cannot perform more than one GSI creation or deletion in a single update.  Could you please explain how you are able to call this method multiple times - even with unique index names?

Comment: @JamesMatson You can _create_ a table with multiple indexes.  You are getting the error while _updating_ the table, because DynamoDB imposes a one-new-GSI-per-update limit.  See edited answer.